# Route a IP address to another & keep src address?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

Consider following:

```
WAN IP1: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa/23 
WAN IP2: bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/25
LAN Subnet: 10.3.0.0/24
```

BOTH WAN addresses were routed to Linux Server, and  Linux server are reachable on both addresses. I want to route bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb to another host on LAN interface (10.3.0.2).

```
INTERNET -- Linux Server
            (aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa/23, bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/25 ens3)
            (10.3.0.1/24 tap0) -------- Router
                                        (10.3.0.2/24 tap0)
                 INTERNET -- ISP NAT -- (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx eth0)
                                        (172.16.1.0/24 br-lan)
```

Now I want to route bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb onto my router on 10.3.0.2 via tap0 (bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb was a address on ens3). So my router will have a public IP address. This is what I have done:

```
ip addr del bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/25 dev ens3 # remove from ens3
ip route add bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb dev tap0   # route it to tap0
```

The graph will be like:

```
INTERNET -- Linux Server
            (aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa/23 ens3)
            (10.3.0.1/24 tap0) -------- Router
                                        (10.3.0.2/24, bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb tap0)
                 INTERNET -- ISP NAT -- (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx eth0)
                                        (172.16.1.0/24 br-lan)
```

And, routing table on Linux Server:

```
% ip -4 route
default via aaa.aaa.aaa.1 dev ens3 onlink 
10.3.0.0/24 via 10.3.0.1 dev tap0 
10.3.0.1 dev ens3  scope link 
aaa.aaa.aaa.0/23 dev ens3  proto kernel  scope link  src aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa 
bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb dev tap0  scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens3  scope link
```

And on my router, I added address `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb`, and I am now able to ping `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` on Linux server.

However, I can't ping `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` on other hosts. So I tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

With that rule I was able to ping `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` on internet. And if I do a traceroute, I can see bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb is behind aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa, i.e.:

```
... 
10. ???
11. aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa                   0.0%    16   45.3  43.6  43.1  45.5   0.8
12. bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb                   0.0%    16   53.7  54.8  51.2  79.4   7.1
```

However, I want the real source IP at tunnel endpoint (10.3.0.2) - now I getting all the traffic  10.3.0.1 on my router because Linux server do SNAT. How should I do that?

Comment: What does the routing table on the hosts that need to ping bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb look like? Where will they send traffic bound for bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb? And where would bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb send traffic bound for their real source IP?

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly confused question, because the commands you gave do not do this, ... *I want to route bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb onto my router on 10.3.0.2 via tap0*. If I understand you right, you want the router to pass thru the Linux server in order to reach the Internet. **If** this is right, then this is how to obtain it, beginning from the configuration in your first figure, *i.e.* neglecting your following commands.

1. On the Linux server, enable *IPv4* forwarding and then issue:

   ```
     iptables -t -nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
     ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 via 10.3.0.2 dev tap0
   ```
2. On the router, where I *presume* IPv4 forwarding is enabled by default:

   ```
   ip route del default
   ip route add default via 10.3.0.1 dev tap0 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 10.8.3.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   ```

The advantage of this is that it does a single level of NATting, on the Linux server, and then routing takes care of everything. If you want the LAN clients to find the Linux server by name (say, it is called LS), add the following line:

```
10.3.0.2    LS
```

to the router's */etc/hosts* file: there is no need to set up a DNS server for such a small need.

However, this does **not** amount to ... *So my router will have a public IP address*, because the public IP address belongs to the Linux server. If someone tries to contact *aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa*, it will be the Linux server which will have to reply. The only exception you can provide is thru *port forwarding*, which means that **all** communications on a given port will be transfered to the router, but you cannot transfer all communications on all ports to the router (which would **really** mean ... *So my router will have a public IP address*).  Unless, of course, your Linux server owns **2 IP addresses**, in which case you could reserve one for the router and the other one for the Linux server.

Comment: Yes, that Linux server did have two IP addresses. Both of aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa and bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb are public IPv4 address, and they are both routed to the Linux server.

Comment: Looks like I did not express myself correctly - my English is not good. I edited the question to make it looks less confusing. What I want to do is "giveaway" one of the IP address on Linux server to router, so it can be access from the Internet. I want router to see the real source IP of clients, so doing NAT on Linux server is not a solution, instead, I want Linux server to route that IP address to my router directly.

Comment: @MorichikaMaho Fine, this is now clear. What I do not understand is how you can have a public, routable IP address on a *tap* device. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It is routed to _eth0_ on Linux Server, and I routed it to _tap0_ on Linux Server using `ip route add bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb dev tap0`.

Comment: @MorichikaMaho So let me get this straight: your Linux server has two ethernet interfaces, *eth0* and *ens3*, with different public IPs? If so, your rerouting it (as you call it) to *tap0* is utterly wrong, you should delete this route. Do the two public IP addresses share the same gateway or not? This is very important.

Comment: Sorry, I have some typo there, all _eth0_ should be _ens3_. I'm not sure how my provider deal with those two IPs - they are not even in a same Class A network and I think they should have different gateway. But I was able to get the secondary IP to work on my Linux server by simply add it to eth0 using `ip` command. So... I guess `aaa.aaa.aaa.1` (gateway of `aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa`) also route `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb`?

Comment: "... by simply add it to eth0 using `ip` command." - Sorry, I mean ens3 there. Always make that mistake.

Comment: @MorichikaMaho It would be helpful to have your routing table at boot, *i.e.* without your hack *ip route add bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb dev tap0*. Also: if you are using a routed OpenvVPN, why have you called the interface *tap0*? It should be called *tun0*.

Comment: The OpenVPN tunnel is a Ethernet (tap) tunnel. Routing was done by my own (i.e. ip addr add, ip route add) . Not quite understand that “at boot” stuff - how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just  figured it out - It is so simple and I don't know why I did not notice that before.

Since my default gateway on router is *NOT* the tunnel server - router is trying to reply packet coming from tun0 via eth0's gateway. Doing SNAT make source address become 10.3.0.1 - Router know where to send them back, and that's why it is working with MASQUERADE.

So, on router, create a new routing table and set its' default gateway as tun0. Then, make source IP `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` look up in that table.

Comment: It is clearly more complex than that. In fact, I do not believe that it can be done, at least not the way you described it in your comments to my post.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Hmm... I can't tell for sure either. It might has something to do with the `169.254.0.0/16` block. I enabled proxy ARP on both `ens3` and `tap0`. When there is a traffic going to `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` from `ens3`, I see `169.254.169.254` ask for who-has `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` on `ens3`, and my router on `tap0` replies it.

Comment: Tap interfaces do not need IP addresses, they should be bridged instead and then the bridge should get an IP address.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes - I find out that I don't need IP on them as I can just let ARP to find where my router is. Proxy ARP will does the same thing as bride here - so I did not use a bridge.